# How to use Group By with where condition to concatenate column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I want to return asset count as per type and also want to concatenate asset ids. I am using `FOR XML` and path which works fairly good but as soon as I add where clause, it does not work as expected.

This is my table schema and query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Asset]
(
    [AssetSeqNumber] [bigint] NULL,
    [AssetType] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Asset] ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (1, N'Tree')

INSERT [dbo].[Asset] ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (2, N'Tree')

INSERT [dbo].[Asset] ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (3, N'Tree')

INSERT [dbo].[Asset] ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (4, N'Barbecue')

INSERT [dbo].[Asset] ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (5, N'Bridge')

INSERT [dbo].[Asset] ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (101, N'Tree')

INSERT [dbo].[Asset] ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (102, N'Tree')
GO
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    AssetType, 
    COUNT(AssetSeqNumber) AS count,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(AssetSeqNumber AS varchar(100))
           FROM Asset
           WHERE AssetType = a.AssetType 
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS AssetIds
FROM 
    Asset AS a
WHERE
    a.AssetSeqNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY 
    AssetType
```

[image]

This query return result for ids which are not in the where condition (i.e. 101,102). I understand it is because inner query check asset types but I can't figure out how to show expected result.

Note: I am using SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2095.3 (X64))

Comment: Need to add `where a.AssetSeqNumber in(1,2,3,4,5)` in Select statement of concat as well.

Comment: What output do you want from the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the where clause for the select statement inside the `STUFF` function as the following:

```
WHERE AssetType = a.AssetType AND AssetSeqNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Also, for your version of SQL Server, you could simplify this by using `STRING_AGG` function as the following:

```
SELECT AssetType, 
       COUNT(*) [Count],
       STRING_AGG(AssetSeqNumber, ',') AssetIds
FROM Asset
WHERE AssetSeqNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY AssetType
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/olQdhZHV) for both queries.

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
drop table if exists #Asset
CREATE TABLE #Asset
(
    [AssetSeqNumber] [bigint] NULL,
    [AssetType] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT #Asset ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (1, N'Tree')

INSERT #Asset ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (2, N'Tree')

INSERT #Asset ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (3, N'Tree')

INSERT #Asset ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (4, N'Barbecue')

INSERT #Asset ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (5, N'Bridge')

INSERT #Asset ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (101, N'Tree')

INSERT #Asset ([AssetSeqNumber], [AssetType]) 
VALUES (102, N'Tree')
GO
```

you should add your condition into your `Xml` query

```
 SELECT
    AssetType, 
    COUNT(AssetSeqNumber) AS count,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CAST(AssetSeqNumber AS varchar(100))
           FROM #Asset
           WHERE AssetType = a.AssetType /*yourcondition*/and AssetSeqNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS AssetIds
FROM 
    #Asset AS a
WHERE
    a.AssetSeqNumber IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY 
    AssetType
```

by consider using SQL Server 2019,you can use `string_agg`

```
SELECT [assettype],
       Count(assetseqnumber)           count,
       String_agg(assetseqnumber, ',') AssetIds
FROM   #asset a
WHERE  a.assetseqnumber IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
GROUP  BY [assettype]
```